# How to have 2 different scales on same Y axis in Python using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spine, twinx

I need to draw 4 X vs Y plots, where X is constant but different Y Values. I used below code to get the plots but need to show the Y scale on either side of the Secondary Y axes (Y Axis 2 in the image), the way Primary Y Axis has (both inward and outward). Right now, it comes on same side of Secondary Y Axis. How to modify the below code to get this done.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=0.9)

twin2 = ax.twinx()
twin3 = ax.twinx()
twin4 = ax.twinx()

twin3.spines['right'].set_position(("axes", 0.0))
twin4.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.0))

p1, = ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="plot1")
p2, = twin2.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], "r-", label="plot2")
p3, = twin3.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], "g-", label="plot3")
p4, = twin4.plot([0, 1, 2], [5, 3, 1], "y-", label="plot4")

ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2)

ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
twin2.set_ylabel("Y Axis 2")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your 4th axes, set [`tick_left`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.YAxis.tick_left.html) and move the **left** spine to the right-hand side:

```
twin4.yaxis.tick_left()
twin4.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', 1.0))
```

[image]